# Detecting Hexagonal Components in Images

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to detect and characterize the size, orientation, and centroid of nearly perfect hexagonal features in images. The built-in `MorphologicalComponents` commands do not seem to DIRECTLY provide the needed functionality (unless I am missing something).

I have coded the following but I am looking for a simpler method. My current methodology is to `EdgeDetect` followed by detection of the hexagon's side by `ImageLines` and then to reconstitute the hexagon suitable for `MorphologicalComponents` to process.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxbKv.png"];
hex = ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"];
GraphicsRow[{img, hex}, ImageSize -> Large]
{col, row} = ImageDimensions[img];
edg = EdgeDetect[GaussianFilter[hex, 2], Method -> {"Canny"}] //  DeleteSmallComponents[#, 500] &
lines = ImageLines[edg, .04, MaxFeatures -> 6];
p0 = Graphics[{Thickness[.01], Orange, lines}];
p1 = Show[edg, p0];
p2 = Show[hex, p0];
GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}, ImageSize -> Large]
Show[MorphologicalComponents[p0 /. Orange -> Black] // Colorize]
ComponentMeasurements[p0 /. Orange -> Black, {"Area", "Centroid"}]
```

[image: trail image]

Comment: What is imag in your code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`ComponentMeasurements`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html) has a lot of interesting and useful measures. To select a hexagon, you can use, for example, the combination of `"Circularity"` (which can be calculated exactly<sup>1</sup> for a hexagon) and "`Elongation`" (which should be zero for a hexagon). Then, you can use `"ConvexVertices"` to get the points of a convex hull. The convex hull will almost always more than 6 vertices. To get a hexagon orientation, calculate the largest distance from the centroid to the vertices. Alternatively, you can also use `"MinimalBoundingBox"` to get the orientation.

Obviously, you can make the code more robust. Also, the last step can be replaced with some kind of "hexagon fitting" to the points. The choice of method depends on your actual aims of the task.

```
bin = Binarize[hex];
comps = DeleteSmallComponents[MorphologicalComponents[bin], 50];

c = Sqrt[\[Pi]]/(Sqrt[2] 3^(1/4));
ceps = 0.1;
eeps = 0.05;

hexagon = SelectComponents[comps, 
            (c - ceps < #Circularity < c + ceps) && (#Elongation < eeps) &];

{pts, center} = First@Values@ComponentMeasurements[hexagon, {"ConvexVertices", "Centroid"}];

vertex = First@MaximalBy[pts, EuclideanDistance[center, #] &];

mbb = First@Values@ComponentMeasurements[hexagon, "MinimalBoundingBox"];

Show[hex, Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[{center, vertex}]}], 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Green], Transparent, Polygon[mbb]}]]
```

[image: Hexagon]

---

<sup>1</sup> *Circularity* is defined as $2 \pi r/p$, with polygonal length $p$ and equivalent disk radius $r$. A hexagon with a side length $a$ has area $(3\sqrt{3}/2)a^2$. Calculating the radius of an equivalent disk: $\pi r^2 =  (3\sqrt{3}/2)a^2 \implies r=3^{3/4}a/(2\pi)$, from which the cirularity can be calculated as $c=2\pi r/(6a) = \sqrt{\pi/(2 \sqrt{3})}$.

Comment: Very helpful thanks